# Read and change combo-box selected item with 4 different possible values

Tags: vb.net, combobox, lines, selecteditem

I have a multi-line textbox that the user can type into; the contents of which are supposed to drive the currently selected item in a combobox.

I have existing code that works for two items currently (Yes & No); however, I now need to make this extend to supporting four items. This is also updated by a timer every 3 seconds, in case if the user manually updated the text. The combobox cannot be typed in, instead it has preset selections.

Also the program is designed to edit properties files.

I'm a little unsure on how to go about doing so.

This is what works for 2 item changes:

```
    Dim lines as Textbox1.lines()
    Dim ach_tr As String = "announce-player-achievements=" 'stuff to be replaced by string ach_ttr
    Dim ach_ttr As String = "" 'empty string to delete string ach_tr
    Dim ach As String = lines(My.Settings.AnnouncePlayerAchievements)'line of string ach_tr
    ach = ach.Replace(ach_tr, ach_ttr)'removes string ach_tr and leaves the value
    If ach = "true" Then
        achievements.SelectedItem = "Yes"
    Else
        achievements.SelectedItem = "No"
    End If
```

I've tried these for 4 items:

```
    Dim lines as Textbox1.lines()
    Dim diff_tr As String = "difficulty="
    Dim diff_ttr As String = ""
    Dim diff As String = lines(My.Settings.Difficulty)
    diff = diff.Replace(diff_tr, diff_ttr)
    If diff = "0" Then
        achievements.SelectedItem = "Peaceful"
    End If
    If diff = "1" Then
        achievements.SelectedItem = "Easy"
    End If
    If diff = "2" Then
        achievements.SelectedItem = "Normal"
    End If
    If diff = "3" Then
        achievements.SelectedItem = "Hard"
    End If
```

And This one:

```
    Dim lines as Textbox1.lines()
    Dim diff_tr As String = "difficulty="
    Dim diff_ttr As String = ""
    Dim diff As String = lines(My.Settings.Difficulty)
    diff = diff.Replace(diff_tr, diff_ttr)
    If diff = "0" Then
        achievements.SelectedItem = "Peaceful"
    Else
        If diff = "1" Then
            achievements.SelectedItem = "Easy"
        Else
            If diff = "2" Then
                achievements.SelectedItem = "Normal"
            Else
                If diff = "3" Then
                    achievements.SelectedItem = "Hard"
                End If
            End If
        End If
    End If
```

Comment: Hi there, could you please provide information on the interaction between the text box and the combobox (how does changing the textbox trigger a selected item change?). Could you also provide the code for the `lines` function, and could you describe in more detail what you're trying to achieve here. If you're after a combobox that users can type into, then you may get on better with this:

Comment: Done adding the extra info for you guys.

Comment: So, if I'm getting this right, the user types / pastes some text into the textbox, which isn't the same as what's in the combo, but maps directly to it? e.g. "1" in the textbox should equal "easy" in the combo?

Comment: The combo box reads the value that is left over from the string subtraction and converts it to a string that the combobox can read. Ex: difficulty (0= Peaceful, 1= Easy, 2= Normal, 3= Hard).                             `code If diff = "1" Then
        achievements.SelectedItem = "Easy"
    End If `

Comment: A little advice here - When coding in VB.Net, you should consider using [Select...Case Statement](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cy37t14y.aspx) instead of nested `If...Else If` statements.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Edit: For future reference Heres a more compact version which works as well:

```
Public LineNum As Globals.LineNumEnum
Dim serveriptr As String = ("server-ip=")
    Dim sipc As String = PropView.OutputRTF.Lines(LineNum.SerIP)
    sipc = sipc.Replace(serveriptr, Nothing)
```

I found my problem. I was trying to change the wrong combobox lol. well at least I learned about dictionaries and the select case. Well thanks for your time.
This is the correct code lol:

```
Dim diff_tr As String = "difficulty="
    Dim diff_ttr As String = ""
    Dim diff As String = lines(My.Settings.Difficulty)
    diff = diff.Replace(diff_tr, diff_ttr)

    If diff = "0" Then
        difficulty.SelectedItem = "Easy"
    ElseIf diff = "1" Then
        difficulty.SelectedItem = "Easy"
    ElseIf diff = "2" Then
        difficulty.SelectedItem = "Normal"
    ElseIf diff = "3" Then
        difficulty.SelectedItem = "Hard"
    End If
```

Comment: FYI, not that it makes a lot of difference in this case, but you could also structure the four `If` statements into one `If` statement, which helps for readability regardless. Use the `ElseIf` keyword to do this.

Comment: Yeah i'm adapting it to the select case because it optimizes my program.

Answer (score 0):

You could do something akin to:

```
var difficultyMap = new Dictionary<string,string>
{
    {"0", "Peaceful"},
    {"1", "Easy"},
    {"2", "Normal"},
    {"3", "Hard"}
};

difficultyCombo.Items = difficultyMap.Values;
updateTimer.Tick += (s,e) => {
    var text = inputTextBox.Text;
    string found;
    if (!difficultyMap.TryGetValue(text))
    {
        MessageBox.Show("unknown difficulty");
        return;
    }
    difficultyCombo.SelectedItem = found;
};
```

This is in C# as I don't know VB very well, but the core concepts should map, I'm also not sure of your exact implementation or requirements, in essence I've done the following:

1. Created a dictionary that goes from the "numeric" difficulty type to the display type for the combo
2. Populated the combo using the display values from the dictionary
3. Whenever the update timer fires, I:

   1. Get the text from the textbox
   2. Try to find the matching difficulty in the dictionary
   3. Display an error or update the combo

Adding `n` number of items to the combo and text input is trivial now, as you just add a new entry to the dictionary.

Comment: i'll give it a shot in an hour when I get back to a computer.

Comment: I figured out that I had been trying to change the wrong combo box. You did however give an idea for another project.